sizeThatFits method in custom layout returns invalid size for subview with fixedSize modifier
I'm writing custom SwiftUI layout and calculate container height based on child sizes. To get height of a subview I use .sizeThatFits(.unspecified) in next method:
public func sizeThatFits(
    proposal: ProposedViewSize,
    subviews: Subviews,
    cache: inout ()
) -> CGSize {
    var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0

    let rows = computeRows(subviews: subviews, proposal: proposal)
    
    rows.forEach { cells in
        let sizes = cells.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        let maxViewHeight = sizes.map(\.height).max() ?? 0
        totalHeight += maxViewHeight
    }
    totalHeight += CGFloat(rows.count - 1) * spacing.height
    return CGSize(
        width: proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions().width,
        height: totalHeight
    )
}

And everything works fine until I add .fixedSize modifier to Text inside view so it does not truncate the text.
Text(description)
    .font(.regular13)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.secondaryLabel)
    .lineLimit(nil)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

The problem is that .sizeThatFits(.unspecified) always returns 121 height of a view but in fact when I add fixedSize modifier it becomes bigger (something about 136).

You can use a GeometryReader for this kind of views for views to be loaded successfully and with accurate measurements.
Something like below should do the trick.
GeometryReader { geometry in
        Text("Your text description goes here")
            .font(.system(size: 13))
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }

Let me know if you find any issues with this.

This doesn't work and doesn't answer the original question. This problem will be solved if I could make my Layout protocol to properly calculate $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) after adding .fixedSize modifier
